# Add SharePoint Calendar to Google Calendar?

Tags: sharepoint, calendar, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am working on a project where I need to push SharePoint calendar events to Google Calendar. Could I apply this by adding SharePoint Calendar to Google Calendar? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There's is no out of the box solution for this however it is discussed [here](http://blog.bendsoft.com/2011/04/sharepoint-to-google-calendar-synchronization/) which will help you to accomplish this. Note that you will need to be or will require a developer to do this.